# JavaScript: cloneNode and appendChild not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code like this -

```
<script>
    var x,m,cloneNodex;
    function addVtier() {
            m.appendChild(cloneNodex);
    }
    function load() {
        x = document.getElementById("vtier#1");
             cloneNodex = x.cloneNode(true);
        m = document.getElementById("main");    
    }
</script>
<body onload = load();>
<div  id = "main">
<table id = "vtier#1" width="100%" class="heading">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button onclick=addVtier();>clone</button> 
            </td>
            <td> 1.Vtier Name:
                <select>
                    <option>Volvo</option>
                    <option>Saab</option>
                    <option>Mercedes</option>
                    <option>Audi</option>
                </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Now my question is that why this appends the cloned node i.e. the table with id="vtier#1" only once and not as many times as the CLONE button is pressed ?

Comment: Should `m.appendChild(nodex);` be `m.appendChild(cloneNodex);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is only one clone.

```
var y = node;
x.appendChild(y);
x.appendChild(y);
```

Only appends y once because there is only one y.

```
<body>
<div  id = "main">
<table id = "vtier#1" width="100%" class="heading">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button>clone</button> 
            </td>
            <td> 1.Vtier Name:
                <select>
                    <option>Volvo</option>
                    <option>Saab</option>
                    <option>Mercedes</option>
                    <option>Audi</option>
                </select>
            </td>   
        </tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>
    (function () {
        var main = document.getElementById("main"),
            vtier = document.getElementById("vtier#1").cloneNode(true);

        document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].addEventListener("click", addClone);

        function addClone() {
            main.appendChild(vtier.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }());
</script>
</body>
```

Also fixed up the code for you by removing globals and using unobtrusive event listeners.

Comment: My problem is that in my original code the div element that i am cloning contains another table having an ADD button which adds rows to table dynamically. Now the problem is if somebody presses this add button first and then click on clone then it loads this new table having more than the default number of rows rather than loading the default table(originally;at the time of page load) having the default number of rows. Now if i add cloneNodex to addVtier() how to get around this problem of cloning the default table ?

Comment: @linusunisfed do both ... added an initial `cloneNode` outside the click handler

Answer (score 2):

Appending a node that is part of the DOM first removes it from its current location so you will not get two clones by adding the same node twice.

This seems to be what you're doing some you only call `cloneNode` once, not every time the clone button is clicked.

Move the `cloneNodex =` out of `load` into `addVtier` and you should get multiple copies.

Comment: Yes m.appendChild(nodex) should be m.appendChild(cloneNodex);

Comment: Why moving the cloneNodex = out of load into addVtier should work ? Can you suggest , Mike ?

Comment: @linusunisfed, `addVtier` is called once per button click.  `load` is called once per page load.  If you want to create one clone per button click you can't do it in `load`.

Comment: Mike, What if i want to create the same clone twice ? If i call cloneNode() everytime i want to create a clone then this cloneNode() could have changed in between the 1st call and the second call. So what shall i do ?

Comment: @linusunisfed, If you're worried about changes, create a clone early on and store it, then clone that in `addVtier`.

Comment: Mike, that solved my problem. ThankYou so much Mike and Raynos. Mike you're simply great.